# ScrollViewer wpf - doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, scrollviewer

I have a wpf application. 
In the window i have a TextBlock which contains a lot of numbers , each number in it's row. I want the scrollViewer to appear when needed. It doesn't work... here is the code

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Margin="5,25,5,0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                 <TextBlock MaxHeight="500" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="TextBlock_Results"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Isn't it a vertical scrollbar that you need?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description. Describe what is happening and what you want it to do.

Comment: "Doesn't work" - means that the scrollviewer doesn't function like it should , there is a scroll on the left side but i can't scroll down to see the items.

Comment: when i deleted the textblock and put instead a listview , the scrollviewer worked perfectly...

Comment: @Yuf yes , this is the code that works -
<TextBox Width="271" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Name="TextBox_AnotherReason" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" TextChanged="TextBox_AnotherReason_TextChanged" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text block in the scroll viewer is not capable of scrolling by default. To enable the ScrollViewer to perform pixel based scrolling you need to set the can content scroll to false.

The visibillity of the two scroll bars are controlled independently. I have hidden the vertical scroll bar in the one bellow.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" Margin="5,25,5,0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock MaxHeight="500" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="TextBlock_Results"
                  Text="a"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```